# Hexagonal coordinate system for labeling vertices that allows the existence of a distance formula

Tags: graph-theory, coordinate-systems

I am working on a Mathematics/Data Science project for the game Settlers of Catan and ran into a very interesting Math problem that has me stumped(knowledge of the game is not necessary to solve this problem). I would like to write a program that allows me to calculate the distance between any two vertices on a 19 Hexagon Grid where one unit is defined as a line that connects any two vertices without passing through a third vertex and does not deviate from the grid.

I need some sort of coordinate system that I can map my data to that will allow me to use a function to find distance. The alternative is embedding the distance between any two points on the grid by-hand (1485 operations), which sounds a bit tedious.

I have been working with a 3-ring system, in which vertices are numbered around each of the 3 rings; but this is only helpful if the points in consideration are within the same ring.

[image: Hexagon Grid]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note if you have the center of your co-ordinate system be the center of the middle hexagon, you can use various symmetries to simplify everything. As for the co-ordinate system values, are the areas between the hexagons just to help in some sort of visualization, or is there actual areas in between them? If the latter, then you'll also need to know how the widths of these areas compare to the hexagon dimensions.

Comment: The hexagon grid is a subset of the triangular grid. The triangular grid is generated by $1$ and $\omega=(1+i\sqrt3)/2$ (in terms of rectangular coordinates, $(1,0)$ and $(1/2,\sqrt3/2)$). Every point in the hexagonal grid is $a+b\omega$ for some integers $a,b$ (but not every point $a+b\omega$ is a vertex in the hexagonal grid). I think the distance you want is $|a|+|b|$ (but you should check this).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you. I should have noted that the attached image slightly misrepresents the grid; I couldn't find a better one. Future commenters: please disregard the gaps between the hexagons.

Comment: The units are just steps through the grid, right? i.e.if I can only hop from the center of one hexagon to the center of an adjacent hexagon, you want to count the number of hops to get from one hexagon to another one.  Is that the question?  Then physical size of hexagons and spaces between them are irrelevant.  Or can a step pass though the space between two hexagons (vertically, for example, jumping over a row) and still count as a one-unit hop?  If not, the  just treat them as staggered rows of rectangles.  You can go up one row, down one row, left, or right.  Each move is one unit.

Comment: @Mars Yes, you are correct that they are just steps, not to do with the size or gaps. Though the steps are from vertex to vertex, not from center to center. So, I would like a way to number these vertices in such a way that lets me produce a function that determines how many units apart two vertices are, travelling along the edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer : the 3D-like coordinate system described in the figure below (which doesn't deserve much commentary).

For example the distance between points with coordinates

$$(a,b,c)=(0,1,0) \ \text{and} \ (a',b',c')=(3,1,-2)$$

(materialized as a dotted path) can be taken as :

$$|a'-a|+|b'-b|+|c'-c| \ = \ 3+0+2 \ = \ 5.$$

(mathematically speaking, it is a $L^1$ distance.)

[image]